# R - Comprehensive regressions

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am trying to do a regression that will try all independent variables, interactions, logs, exponents, whatever else to generate a good model. My data have 10 independent variables, one dependent variable, and 134 rows in the data frame. Is there a function or method that would help with this? Is it even reasonable? Thanks!

Comment: This does not seem reasonable from a statistical perspective. You might want to first get some statistical advice from [stats.se] before trying to write any code. Do you not have any sort of specific hypothesis you are trying to test with your data?

Comment: One reason this is probably an unreasonable approach is that the more parameters you use, the more likely you are to overfit and/or to fool yourself into finding a relationship that is due to chance and not any real connection. See https://www.americanscientist.org/article/the-statistical-crisis-in-science for more explanation.

Comment: Also see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging.  "The process of data dredging involves testing multiple hypotheses using a single data set by exhaustively searching—perhaps for combinations of variables that might show a correlation, and perhaps for groups of cases or observations that show differences in their mean or in their breakdown by some other variable."